# PNGs in Lotus Notes emails - some users see a very pixelated graphic

Tags: lotus-notes

I send out internal HTML emails to all employees in my company from time to time. I write the code in an HTML editor and point to some graphics on an WordPress server.

A user (I believe only one) reported the header graphic is very pixelated, and they are the actual designer of the graphic. They sent me a screen shot and indeed it is pixelated. But mine is not nor is it pixelated on any other users who I have tested it on.

She is running 9.0.0 and in general we run that and above.

I have hunted for a setting that would possibly cause this in the client to no avail.

What in the world could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the user using the Notes internal browser instead of the embedded operating system browser for displaying MIME mails.
Please check notes.ini entry `BrowserRenderDisable=1` on the users' machine or check the setting `Disable embedded browser for MIME mail` in the `Basic Notes Client Configuration` tab of the user preferences

Check out [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21282102) for further explanations. It's for Notes 8, but the same is still true for Notes 9

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I am going to check with the user and will follow up.